# Keep table in single page on PDF

Tags: dita, dita-ot

I'm using Dita-OT 2.1.0 and I have tried to customize PDF output for my Dita document. My document consists of many tables which can be short or multiple pages long. What I would like to do is to prevent tables from breaking to multiple pages if possible. For example I'd like to have a new page before table if that prevents table from breaking to two pages.

What I tried was to put this into my custom.xsl

```
<xsl:attribute-set name="tbody.row">
<xsl:attribute name="keep-with-next.within-page">always</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:attribute-set>
```

That seems to do that rows stay kind of on same page but if one row is long enough to go to next page then it goes there, instead of just moving whole table there.. Any ideas how to fix this?

With setting

```
<xsl:attribute-set name="table">
    <xsl:attribute name="keep-together.within-page">always</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:attribute-set>
```

It still doesn't work. Now tables stay on same page but tables longer than 1 page don't show up fully.

Answer (score 1):

You should also try something like:

`<xsl:attribute name="keep-together.within-page">1</xsl:attribute>`

Possible explanation for the answer could be found here:
http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect3/keepsNbreaks.html

Comment: This looks promising. Thanks! Only problem so far is that there's black border on the end of every page indicating end of table even if the table goes on to the next page. So one table has kind of "two" endings but only one "start" border.

Comment: I'm not sure about that, might be a bug in Apache FOP. Maybe you could also try a commercial processor like XEP or Antenna House.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is a tricky one because you have to trade flexibility for the look of the output. You could add an outputclass attribute to the table to cause the output to break prior to the table and change the table processing so that tables are enclosed in a block with a break-before attribute applied in the fo. I haven't looked at the base code for tables in a bit but it might require you to create a choose scenario to apply the block.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do what you want in a one-pass process.

If a table can fit on a page you can use keep-together.within-page to force that, but at the time you generate the table there's no general way to know how big the table will be.

FO does not provide any way to say "keep the entire table within the page if and only if the entire page will fit, otherwise, break it as needed".

There are ways to do multi-pass processing so that you can tune the table layout more precisely but that would require some custom programming and is dependent on a specific FO engine (although there is one option that will work with either Antenna House or FOP: http://www.w3.org/community/ppl/wiki/XSLTExtensions)

One compromise solution is to use keep-with-next on the first *n* rows to ensure that a table doesn't break too early but that only works if the rows are a consistent depth--if the row depth can vary widely then you could still have a situation where the first *n* rows exceed a page and then boom.